# How to apply `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract specific substring from string?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I have the following string `011/2020-PL00-70-31` (it could slightly different for example `011/2020-PL00-70-3` or `011/2020-PL00-70-310`). I need to extract from the string all string before last `-`. As a result of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` of `011/2020-PL00-70-310` I need to get `011/2020-PL00-70` only, i.e. without last 4 symbols (but in some case it could be without 2 or 3 symbols).

I am new to regular expression in PL SQL, so sorry for question if it is so easy.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might try `REGEXP_REPLACE(whatever, '(-[^-]+)$', '')`.

Comment: The expression `REGEXP_REPLACE(whatever, '(-[^-]+)$')` finds `-31`, but not remove. I cannot apply `replace` because there could be another matching of `-31` in the string.

Comment: It should find a minus followed by at least one non-minus – but *only* at the *end* of the string (`$`!), so any intermediate occurrence should remain untouched.

Comment: @Aconcagua, Please post your comment as an answer. This is the correct solution.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Added – didn't post before because I hadn't tested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex capture group `()` to get only the part you need from a pattern.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(sample, '^(.*)-\d+$',1,1,'',1) AS sample2
FROM sample_table
```

| SAMPLE2 |
| --- |
| 011/2020-PL00-70 |
| 011/2020-PL00-70 |
| 011/202-PL00-70 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=50753038fe2e8199f08ceea8970583dc)*

Test of the regex pattern [here](https://regexr.com/6caok)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I think you're overthinking your solution using regex. Your hyphen is always the third hyphen so you can just use `INSTR` to find the third occurrence. See this query here:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(sample, 1, INSTR(sample, '-', 1, 3)-1) AS match
FROM sample_table;
```

I have linked my results with a SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c30207/7/0

Answer (score 0):

You might just replace the trailing digits away:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(whatever, '(-[^-]+)$', '')
```

The regex catches a minus sign and any subsequent non-minus characters (`[^-]+`; alternatively you can match against digits only: `\d+`) – *if* they are located at the end of the string (`$`), so intermediate digits are protected.